# android: How can I check package to be assured that is a file exist?

Tags: android, imageview, image

In my project I have a Picture that through program, I extracted pixels, manipulate those pixels and then saved it in my package

> FileOutputStream fos = new
>   FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
>   + "/newPicture.bmp");

so, it saves my picture in

> /data/data/my_package_name/files

Now, I want to replace my default picture with this new picture. Actually, since I don't have this new picture, default picture should be shown. when new picture prepared, default picture should be replace with new one.

my main problem is How can I check to be assured that is new picture exist? if not exist show default picture, if exist show new picture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a service in android that will monitor your old file whether any update has happened.
If there is change in timestamp for the file, then new file has been updated.Get this status from your other Activity or View class before you are performing the file operations.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks dea UNNI, I'm trying to find a page to explain service. Thanks again